# generating PDF on the fly using TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

i'm using TCPDF library to generate a PDF (bill) on the fly and send it via email. It all works but i have a weird problem. When i send the email to a gmail account everything is fine, but when i send it to my mail server i get the email with the pdf but when i open it it doesn't open and i get a message "Adobe reader could not open file.pdf because it's either not a supported format or because the file has been damaged." (the pdf in the email is blank).

I save the PDF into a string like so:

```
$attachment = $pdf->Output("mypdf.pdf","E");
$attachment = chunk_split($attachment);
```

and send it via email like so:

```
 $header .= "--".$separator.$eol; 
 $header .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name='mypdf.pdf'".$eol;
 $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
 $header .= "Content-Disposition= attachment".$eol.$eol;
 $header .= $attachment;
```

i'm sending the email with php mail function.

The funny thing is if i force the download of the pdf, like so:

$attachment = $pdf->Output("mypdf.pdf","D");

the file is OK and opens without a problem! But if i change it back to "E" it doesn't work.

The other weird thing is that some times i can open the pdf (that i got on my mail server) without a problem, but the next time it wont work (even if i send the exact same email).

Does any one have any idea what is going on? I would like to avoid saving the pdf on the local server.

Comment: Have you encoded your `$attachement`?

Comment: $pdf->Output("mypdf.pdf","E"); returns a base64 encoded string. i've  also tried encoding it myself but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why you avoid saving pdf file? You can save it with `"F"` parameter. After mail has sent you can delete it with `unlink` function

Comment: don't see the point of writing a file if it's going to be erased. I'm using this option as a last resort.

Comment: I has done before same thing with you. I checked if($mail->send() == true){ unlink("file path"); }  It works.

Comment: I use to do this creating a file because it's easier to attach.

Answer (score 0):

I see some minor flaws:

- `Content-Disposition=` should be `Content-Disposition:`
- You should end your attachment with `"--".$separator."--"`

I'm not sure, if this fixes your problems. Anyway I think it's quite complicated to create all the headers manually. I use PEARs Mail_Mime for this task since years and you will find a lot of simple ready to use solutions.